# Merging data from old SQL Server database to new updated SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server database server with customer database which is being used to store and retrieve data. I plan to extend the database further by adding new tables and relations. Can I copy the current database make the necessary modifications and then import or merge data from old database to this new one?

Answer (score 2):

From:
http://okayguru.blogspot.in/2012/03/copy-one-database-to-another-database.html

There are several ways to do this, below are two options:

---

**Option 1:**

- Right click on the database you want to copy
- Choose 'Tasks' > 'Generate scripts'
- 'Select specific database objects'
- Check 'Tables'
- Mark 'Save to new query window'
- Click 'Advanced'
- Set 'Types of data to script' to 'Schema and data'
- Next, Next

You can now run the generated query on the new database.

---

**Option 2:**

- Right click on the database you want to copy
- 'Tasks' > 'Export Data'
- Next, Next
- Choose the database to copy the tables to
- Mark 'Copy data from one or more tables or views'
- Choose the tables you want to copy
- Finish